# Detecting and removing blank area in image

Tags: python-3.x, orientation, scikit-image

I have a collection of 35.000 greyscale scans of different paper-based forms. Some of the paper forms are in landscape and some in portrait orientation. Some of the landscape forms were scanned in portrait mode by mistake. This results in a scan, that has whitespace in the lower two thirds (approximately). Of course there is some noise in the whitespace.

What I need to do is to remove the whitespace from the portrait scan and convert it to a landscape scan. That should be pretty simple, but I'm obviously new to image processing.

So any help would be highly appreciated. Sorry for not being able to post an example, because the scans contain personal medical data.

EDIT:

```py
from skimage import io
from skimage.util import crop
import numpy as np

image = io.imread(convert_image_path + filename)
crop_image = crop(image, ( image.shape[0]/5, image.shape[0]), ((0, image.shape[1])), (0,image.shape[2]))
```

and the result is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-6cc7c0d534bf> in <module>
      4 
      5 image = io.imread(convert_image_path + filename)
----> 6 crop_image = crop(image, ( image.shape[0]/5, image.shape[0]), ((0, image.shape[1])), (0,image.shape[2]))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/util/arraycrop.py in crop(ar, crop_width, copy, order)
     58                    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(crops))
     59     if copy:
---> 60         cropped = np.array(ar[slices], order=order, copy=True)
     61     else:
     62         cropped = ar[slices]

ValueError: Non-string object detected for the array ordering. Please pass in 'C', 'F', 'A', or 'K' instead
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, or what are you struggling with?

Comment: I tried some code examples I found and don't seem to be able to slice the image the way I want it - ends with errors or does nothing. There must be a simple way to achieve that, but nothing worked so far. Adding to the difficulty is, that I can't show the image in my Jupiter notebook. But that is a different question. I edited the question to demonstrate one of my failures.

Comment: Your question is still quite vague on what you want, do you know which images are in landscape? Do you want the image to remove white spaces from all images, how much white is there in other parts of the image? What do you want to do with images that have a whitespace in that bottom area?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer to what I think are your three main questions.

1. How to slice an image
2. How to rotate an image 90 degrees.
3. How to detect large white areas.

### Inputs

I generated the following input

[image]

using:

```
import numpy as np

from skimage import io

portrait = np.full(shape=(250, 150), fill_value=255, dtype=np.uint8)
portrait[:200, :] = 0

io.imsave("portrait.png", portrait)
```

---

#### How to slice

For slicing we can directly use numpy, which has a coordinate system starting in the left top, with `row`, `column` order (`y`, `x`).

In order to slice the bottom part of the image we have to select the top part, by using  `[:200]`, which take all the rows above the 200. (dropping the last 50 white rows).

```
from skimage import io

portrait = io.imread("portrait.png")
sliced = portrait[:200]
io.imsave("portrait slice.png", sliced)
```

[image]

---

#### How to rotate

For rotation there is a build in method `rot90` in `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

portrait = io.imread("portrait.png")
rotated = np.rot90(portrait, k=-1)  # Rotate clockwise, k=1, rotate counter clockwise
io.imsave("portrait rotated.png", rotated)
```

[image]

---

#### How to detect white areas

For detecting large white areas, you can look at the average values in a row and column. Based on that you can decide whether there is enough white to indicate it as a blank region.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby, count
from skimage import io

portrait = io.imread("portrait.png")

# We take the average value for every row.
rows = np.average(portrait, axis=1)

# This returns the row indices that have a gray value higher than 240
white_rows = np.squeeze(np.argwhere(rows > 240), axis=-1)

# This locates the groups of consecutive rows that are largely white
groups = groupby(white_rows, key=lambda item, c=count(): item - next(c))
for index, group in groups:
    white_region = list(group)
    
    # Only slice regions that contains at least so many largely white rows. 
    if len(white_region) > 30:
        slicing = [white_region[0], white_region[-1]]
        print(slicing)
```

Example output:

```
[200, 249]
```

So now we know where there is a large white area in the image. In your case you might want to verify that the region is exclusively in the bottom part of the image. This can be done by filtering the white rows on low values.

```
white_rows = white_rows[white_rows > 150]
```

This means that the white rows have to be past the 150th pixel row.

### Extra

To detect if the image is in portrait or not you can use the image shape

```
portrait = image.shape[0] > image.shape[1]
```